# no database selected php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have a trouble with this T_T this is a searching/consult script for cars parts

this is the php

```
    <?php

if ($_POST['buscar'])
{
// Tomamos el valor ingresado
$buscar = $_POST['palabra'];

// Si está vacío, lo informamos, sino realizamos la búsqueda
if(empty($buscar))
{
echo "No se ha ingresado una cadena a buscar";
}else{

//Conexión a la base de datos
$servidor = "localhost"; //Nombre del servidor
$usuario = "root"; //Nombre de usuario en tu servidor
$password = "1234"; //Contraseña del usuario
$base = "db_maquinas"; //Nombre de la BD
$con = mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password) or die("Error al conectarse al servidor");
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repuestos WHERE 'id','descripcion' LIKE '%$buscar%' ORDER BY id", $con) or die(mysql_error($con)); 
mysql_select_db($base, $con) or die("Error al conectarse a la base de datos");

$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);

// Tomamos el total de los resultados
if($result) { $total = mysql_num_rows($result); } else { die('Invalid query' . mysql_error($con)); }


      echo "<table border = '1'> \n"; 
//Mostramos los nombres de las tablas 
echo "<tr> \n"; 

while ($field = mysql_fetch_field($result)){ 
            echo "<td>$field->name</td> \n"; 
} 
      echo "</tr> \n"; 

do { 
            echo "<tr> \n"; 

            echo "<td>".$row["id"]."</td> \n"; 

            echo "<td>".$row["descripcion"]."</td> \n"; 

            echo "<td>".$row["cantidad"]."</td> \n"; 

            echo "</tr> \n"; 

      } while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));

            echo "</table> \n"; 

echo "¡ No se ha encontrado ningún registro !"; 
} 
}
?>
```

that when on the form i press "Send or Search" this send me to another page that says "NO DATABASE SELECTED"

I hope somebody can help me with that.. 
PD: i'm using a localhost DB with PhpMyAdmin i have items on tables, i verified tables not empty...

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You select your database *after* you attempt to run queries. Place the code *before* you attempt to run queries:

```
mysql_select_db($base, $con) or die("Error al conectarse a la base de datos");
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repuestos WHERE 'id','descripcion' LIKE '%$buscar%' ORDER BY id", $con) or die(mysql_error($con));
```

FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Excellent, now when i send again. says me "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''descripcion' LIKE '%1%' ORDER BY id' at line 1"    i'm using last xampp with phpmyadmin, idk

Comment: `WHERE 'id','description'` is invalid syntax.

Comment: i change it to `WHERE id, descripcion LIKE` but send me the same message.

Comment: `WHERE id LIKE '%$buscar%' AND descripcion LIKE '%$buscar%'`

Comment: good one! now i think I hope.. pls god say yes.. >.< is the last erro now send me error on different line.. this time is Line 32 that says 
`Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\xampp\htdocs\maquinas2000\paginas\buscarepuestos.php on line 32
Invalid query`  the line 32 is. -> ´$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);´ :D thx

Comment: That's odd. It's like your query disappeared.

Comment: yes like that... :S i have one week like a idiot only on this php is the last thing for put the page 100% working

Comment: Since your query is hardcoded into mysql_query() I don't know how that could happen.

Answer (score 0):

place the `mysql_selectdb()` before the `mysql_query()`.